# Find the area of these 2 specific regions

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, area

Here is the question....[image]

When I put it into wolfram to just get a good visual of it...it looks like this...
[image]

I believe this is the formula we use
[image]

The problem is, I don't quite understand what they are asking for? Are they saying that they want the area of those two identical regions that range horizontally from 0-pi and from -2pi to -pi. and vertically from around 12-15?
Not sure how to find the area for that. That would be cool if you go do the area of one side from -2pi to pi and then to the area of the other side from 0 to pi. That does not seem to be the correct way to do it though?

Let me know what you guys think!

Thanks to all who help!

Comment: You need to plot these in polar coordinates. Then you will get two closed curves, and thus the meaning of "inside" and "outside" should become clear.

Answer (score 1):

This is the plot that you need.[image]

Maple code:

`plot(
     [6*sin(t)+6, 18*sin(t)], t= 0..2*Pi, 
     coords= polar, 
     legend= [6*sin(t)+6, 18*sin(t)], 
     scaling= constrained
);`

Comment: How did you get that?? @CarlLove

Comment: Maple. It's math software---the main competitor of Wolfram's __Mathematica__.